# Is it normal for the Delete key not to work when trying to rename a DB/table in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I try to rename a database or a table in SSMS 2014 (with CU6 applied), by clicking and selecting the DB or table in the Object Explorer and then pressing F2 to edit the name. The Delete key on my keyboard will not delete the character to the right of the cursor or whatever is selected.

Is this just a problem on my end or did I find one heck of a bug?

Comment: As utterly ridiculous as it is it might convince you to just use sp_rename which is easier and faster then finding the object in the tree in the first place.

Comment: To add insult to injury, I love how the SSMS splash screen says "Powered by Visual Studio". Well, guess what, in Visual Studio the Delete key works as it should in the SQL Server Object Explorer pane, allowing you to properly edit DB and Table names. Maybe the Splash Screen should instead say, "**Powered by a version of Visual Studio which through sheer developer incompetence and lack of QA testing of basic functionality we somehow managed to break. PS, We're not going to fix it, either!**"

Comment: May have something to do with the fact that, when the pane is not in the object rename mode, Delete is handled to delete the item highlighted. Apparently, for some reason it was easier for the developers to disable the button rather than temporarily restore the "normal" handling.

Comment: @Andriy, don't know what they did, but like I said it works perfectly in Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer which handles all of the exact same actions as SSMS.

Comment: Just found that bug, too. Can't believe that Microsoft is not fixing this. This must be extremely simple to solve !

Comment: @AndriyM that's also my thought. Otherwise I don't see how this bug cannot be fixed within 5 minutes.

Comment: In what world is doing this in the object explorer even an acceptable practice? ALL database changes should be scripted and in source control just like other code. Doing it through the Object Explorer in SSMS is professionally irresponsible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known issue that's been closed as "won't fix."

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/570758/cannot-use-delete-key-in-ssms-and-object-explorer

Comment: I wonder why it can't be fixed in 5 minutes. What's the real problem behind it?

Comment: I just read the Microsoft Connect item and it's unfu**ing believable!

Comment: @Vland It's really suspicious. Possibly it's because you can use "Del" to delete a whole entry, when you are not in edit mode ?